# Getting empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, fetch, concatenation

I have declared three arrays **dronesList**, **ndzDrones**, **pilotsList**. After all the conditions are executed, I am getting updated data of **dronesList** and **ndzDrones** but the **pilotsList** is empty, although I'm receiving the data and **pilotsList** is updated inside the condition after pushing but outside of condition getting **Empty[]** of **pilotsList**. Can't figure what I'm missing here.
Any help will be appriciated

```
let dronesList = []
    let ndzDrones = []
    
    try {
        const xml = await fetch(
            "https://assignments.reaktor.com/birdnest/drones"
          ).then((res) => res.text())
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error)
          })
        const jsonData = parser.parse(xml)
        const dronesData = jsonData.report.capture.drone;
        dronesList = dronesData;

        if(dronesList !== ""){
            
            dronesList.map((drone) =>{
                const x = Number(drone.positionX)
                const y = Number(drone.positionY)
                if(checkVoilation(x, y)){
                    ndzDrones = ndzDrones.concat(drone)
                }
            })
        }

        let pilotsList = []
        if(ndzDrones !== ""){
            ndzDrones.forEach(async (drone) => {
                const serial = drone.serialNumber
                const response = await fetch(`https://assignments.reaktor.com/birdnest/pilots/${serial}`)
                const data = await response.json()
                pilotsList = pilotsList.concat(data)
            })
        }
        console.log(dronesList) //Output [drones]
        console.log(ndzDrones) //Output [ndzDrones]
        console.log(pilotsList) //Output [] Empty Array
        res.status(200).json(pilotsList)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message})
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an idea of what the data looks like after it comes back the fetch call.  As a matter of fact, that would be a good way for *you* to debug this issue, just just some good old-fashioned hard-coded data as part of your process toward a solution.

Comment: @Dexygen after **concat** pilotsList inside the condition is like this ```[
  {
    pilotId: 'P-bDDYUSvaMO',
    firstName: 'Tate',
    lastName: 'Beatty',
    phoneNumber: '+210445710227',
    createdDt: '2022-11-18T04:42:18.294Z',
    email: 'tate.beatty@example.com'
  }
]```    While outside condition its empty

Comment: @DreamBold already using async/await.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-sanderson-uhw80i?file=/src/App.js Please have a look at this. can you replicate your issue here?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/13561410) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const pilotsList = await Promise.all(ndzDrones.map(async (drone) => {
  const serial = drone.serialNumber
  const response = await fetch(`https://assignments.reaktor.com/birdnest/pilots/${serial}`)
  const data = await response.json()
  return data
})).flat()
```